# If element does not have attributes X and Y?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove elements that doesn't have some attributes.

To remove an unique element I'm doing like this:

```
$('ul li:not([data-caracter='+chosenCaract+'])').remove();
```

its working fine, but i dont know how to check if element doesn't have two or more attributes.. How can i do that?

Comment: You mean? `$('ul li:not([data-caracter='+chosenCaract+'][xxx=yyy])').remove();`

Comment: You probably just want `'ul li:not([attr1][attr2])'` if you're not worried about attributes values

Answer (score 2):

To remove all elements that don't have both characteristics you could use

```
$('ul li:not([data-x='+chosenx+'][data-y='+choseny+'])').remove();
```

But at this point you might want to think again about the whole design. An alternative would be to use `filter` :

```
$('ul li').filter(function(){
     var data = $(this).data();
     return !(data.x=='somevalue' && data.y=='someotherone');
}).remove();
```

Comment: I understand what you said, in fact i think the first works ass well, but i should use the second alternative you put there but it doesnt seem to work, im doing something wrong. if i console.log(data.caracter) it returns me all data-caracter and it doesnt filter. let me show you the the full code jsfiddle.net/u5fpZ @dystroy